# form of primes:prime plus a power of 2?

Tags: prime-numbers

is every prime p equals another prime p' plus or minus a power of 2? p=p'+/-2^n? are there infinitely many primes not of this form?

Comment: To make your questions better, you might want to include some background or motivation. Why are you interested? What have you tried already? etc.

Comment: one  can look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49751/chens-theorem-with-congruence-conditions/49782#49782

Comment: i changed the question according to the answer that Gjergji gave me

Comment: is this allowed?


Comment: It's very much discouraged since it makes the thread look like nonsense. Changing your question to make an existing answer a non-answer is something like inviting to treat somebody to dinner, then slipping out after the meal, sticking them with the bill.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

127 and 331 are counterexamples. It was a conjecture of Polignac that every odd number can be written as a sum of an odd prime and a power of two, but many counterexamples have been found. They are called ["obstinate numbers"](http://oeis.org/A133122). Erdos has proved that there is an infinite arithmetic progression of obstinate numbers.

Edit (response to the added question): There will be infinitely many such prime counterexamples as a corollary to Erdos' theorem and Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. See "Not always buried deep: selections of problems from analytic and combinatorial number theory" by P. Pollack.

Comment: if i allow p=p'-2^n too?


Comment: Yes! Apparently a counterexample to that was given by Cohen and Selfridge. 47,867,742,232,066,880,047,611,079 and the proof is left as an exercise :)

Comment: This last number is a counterexample to being a sum or difference of a prime and a power of 2, by the way.

Comment: do you have a good answer to this closed question too?http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49730/twin-primes-etc-closed

Comment: and a kind of joke :if i allow p=p'+/-2^m+/-2^n?

Comment: thnx a lot as for the other question?

Comment: i don't have an answer to the other question.

Comment: @asterious gantzounis: Crocker showed that there are infinitely many odds not of that form, see https://oeis.org/A156695  I don't know if there are infinitely many primes not of that form -- it's been a while since I read his papers -- but I suspect the answer is "yes".

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi where can i find the proof that there exists a $p \neq p' \pm 2^n$ ?